# HP ProLiant Server Drive compatibility

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant

I have a DL360 g7 & a DL380 g8 server in my office, and I'm interested in replacing my g8 drives for newer drives with more storage space.

My question is - are the g8 drives compatible in the g7 drive slots or do they require a different tray/caddie?

I am aware of the fact that between g7 and g8 the caddies switched to "smart" caddies, thus rendering the g7 drives incompatible with g8 slots, but I'm wondering if the opposite is also true - i.e - whether the g8 drives are incompatible with the g7 slots?

Comment: You should rephrase this or give a little more detail about what you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a huge change between G7 and Gen8 when it comes to 2.5" disk caddies - they simply won't fix into each other. To be fair the Gen8/9 caddies offer a lot of additional functionality that the G7 version couldn't but it was rather a testing time for a lot of organisations who had become used to generation-to-generation interoperability.

So to confirm, they're not forward or backwardly compatible.

Answer (score 5):

The bare disks are compatible. Assuming you speaking of regular 2.5" SAS disks.

However, [drives for G7 servers are cheap](http://www.ebay.com/itm/170577592050?_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT). Buy some from eBay and you won't have to deal with the caddy swap or any other unnecessary changes.